# Does Lexico have dictionary entries in American English?

Tags: discussion, resources

My recollection is that the old Oxford Dictionaries site had entries in both American English and "British & World English", which could be accessed through different urls.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en) has British & World English entries, whose addresses have the format `https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/` followed by the headword. Is there any way to access Oxford's American English entries through the Lexico site? Much of the information is the same, but the American English pronunciation guides are often different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The American English dictionary is back again in its full form. From [About | Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/about):

> **3. How can I switch between the UK and US dictionaries?**
>
> When performing a search, select the drop-down menu next to the search bar (or below the search bar on mobile) to select the dictionary you'd like to use. This drop-down menu also allows searches of our grammar articles or the thesaurus. The selector will remember your preference for subsequent searches.

This update seems to have happened sometime in February 2020.

Confusingly, though, the entries of the British dictionary is under `https://www.lexico.com/definition/...` while the American dictionary is under `www.lexico.com/en/definition/...`.

Old links to the American dictionary on Oxford Living Dictionaries (`en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/...`) now redirect to the corresponding pages.

Answer (score 8):

The [Lexico FAQs](https://www.lexico.com/en/about) say that this is no longer possible in general:

> When searching in the English Dictionary, a toggle between US and UK English is no longer provided. We treat all of English as one dataset, but default with British and World English (which is equivalent to the UK Dictionary toggle selection). That means when you look up a word, you will most likely find the British and World English spelling and pronunciation. However, some US English words don’t exist within this dataset, and in that case, you may come across a US entry for a word as there is no British and World English option. The main spellings and pronunciations for the US entries will be US English.
>
> If you are looking for a British and World English/US comparison, feel free to use Lexico for your British and World English needs and Dictionary.com for US spelling and pronunciation comparisons.

Comment: Hmm...lexico.com and dictionary.com are owned by the same outfit? I suspect that what we are seeing here are steps limiting free content and leading to paywalls.

Comment: @Xanne no? Lexico is owned by Oxford University Press and dictionary.com is owned by Rock Holdings. I don't think the two are connected that much. Referring those looking for US English to an American site doesn't seem that weird to me. It's like migrating questions from one SE site to another, except that the two are in different networks from different countries.

Comment: @JJJ: Lexico is hosted by Dictionary.com, which has acquired a license from Oxford University Press for the English Oxford Dictionaries content. So it represents a collaboration between Dictionary.com and Oxford University Press.

Comment: @sumelic my bad, I thought I was looking at Lexico's Wikipedia page but it instead redirects to the page for Oxford Dictionaries. I guess they're all in cahoots now. I guess that's the trade-off for wanting quality work (which a dictionary is, I guess?) for free. Back in the day we used to buy dictionaries, now everyone wants the same for free with the convenience of just having to type the word. Next step is probably some advertisements / sponsored articles / advertorials.